# Pipe txt file to spd-say?

Tags: bash, pipe, text-to-speech, txt

I have a file in .txt format, called `foo.txt`. It has many line breaks, but I don't care about how my output treats them. I want to pipe the entire contents of the .txt file to `spd-say`, so that I will get the entire .txt read out to me by the text to speech. How can this be done? I was hoping that `cat foo.txt | spd-say` would do the trick, but it hasn't. I've tried to look this up and I'm getting the feeling that I'm missing something utterly basic.

Comment: Try `spd-say "$(< foo.txt)"`.  That passes the entire contents of `foo.txt` as a string argument to `spd-say`.  See the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: @pjh That looks like an answer. It will be worth posting it as one.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cat foo.txt | spd-say -e
```

works, but I doubt that's the best way.